# LDAP Authentication Error

Tags: java, spring, grails, active-directory, ldap

Im getting an error in grails when trying to use LDAP authentication to find a user using AD authentication. This is the code I have from the grails side:

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        ArrayList<String> roles=new ArrayList<String>(2);
        roles.add("ROLE_USER");
        try {
            GldapoSchemaClassForUser.findAll( directory: "user", filter: "(userPrincipalName=${username})" ).each{ user ->
            def userName = user.cn
            user.memberOf.each{ groupListing ->
            String groupName=groupListing.substring(3, groupListing.indexOf(','));
            if (groupName.equals("Admin")) {
                roles.add("ROLE_ADMIN");
            } else if (groupName.equals("User")) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage())
        }
        return new User(username)
    }
```

It hits the catch block when it tries to access this line above:

> GldapoSchemaClassForUser.findAll( directory: "user", filter:
>   "(userPrincipalName=${username})" )

showing this error message:

> org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49
>   - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525, vece

According to documentation this error suggests that a 525 error means an invalid user but I have tested using an LDAP explorer tool and it connects to the user fine with the same details.

In the app-config file I have the following ldap settings:

- ldap.directories.user.url=ldap://sbs.testsbs.local
- ldap.directories.user.base=OU=staff,DC=skills,DC=local
- ldap.directories.user.userDn=OU=staff,DC=skills,DC=local
- ldap.directories.user.password=Pa55w0rd

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the app-config LDAP settings.

The **ldap.directories.user.userDn** setting has been populated with a container, the same as you specified in **ldap.directories.user.base**.

However this should be the DN of the *user object* that is performing the search, something along the lines of **ldap.directories.user.userDn=CN=myAppUser,OU=staff,DC=skills,DC=local**

The `525` error means *user not found* but in this case pertains to the user logging in, and not the user you are searching for.